# Red flower with yellow star in center with fig-like leaves

Tags: species-identification, botany

This plant has red flowers with a yellow star in the center and has fig-like leaves.

- Location: Toronto
- Size: 4ft tall by 3ft wide
- Date: July 25th, 2020

What is it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are common hollyhocks, they come in many colors. As a little kid from Chicago , I was impressed by flowers taller than me when visiting rural Wisconsin . Then the standard for hiding/decoration outhouses.